# gdb - print macros names instead of a values

Tags: c, gdb

Is it possible to UNexpand macros in gdb ?

I've compiled binary with -g3 , and I can see macro definitions:

```
(gdb) info macro  NGX_CORE_MODULE
Defined at /path/src/core/ngx_conf_file.h:70
  included at /path/src/core/ngx_core.h:86
  included at /path/src/core/ngx_cycle.c:9
#define NGX_CORE_MODULE 0x45524F43
(gdb)
```

but when i see at the variable, i see numeric value instead of the macro name

```
(gdb) p/x cycle->modules[0]->type
$17 = 0x45524f43
(gdb)
```

is it possible to get something like this:

```
(gdb) p cycle->modules[0]->type
$17 = NGX_CORE_MODULE
(gdb)
```

I'v tried user-defined function like this:

```
define expand_module_type_macro
if $arg0 == 0x45524F43
   print "NGX_CORE_MODULE"
else 
if $arg0 == 0x464E4F43
   print "NGX_CONF_MODULE"
else
   print $arg0
end
end
end
```

and it works

```
(gdb) expand_module_type_macro cycle->modules[0]->type
$18 = "NGX_CORE_MODULE"
(gdb)
```

but it has no practical use, because i can't use it with complex output:

```
(gdb) printf "module type=%s\n", expand_module_type_macro cycle->modules[0]->type
No symbol "expand_module_type_macro" in current context.
(gdb) set $m = expand_module_type_macro cycle->modules[0]->type
No symbol "expand_module_type_macro" in current context.
(gdb)
```

Comment: The C compiler does not know that a C variable is form this macro. It was done by C preprocessor, the substitution was in plain text, the information about that is lost. You want to assume that all(!) variables that have the value of `0x45524f43` come from this macro?

Comment: compiler DOES know about macros - see -g3 option
and, yes it is ok that all numbers 0x45524f43 will be printed as "NGX_CORE_MODULE" , or i want some function to do so, see post

Comment: It shows you the line where the macro is defined. But is has no information about the connection between the variable and the macro. Because that information is lost. Because `#define A 1 \n int b = A;` is substituted by preprocessor into `#define A 1 \n int b = 1;` before compilation. And the compiler does not know that b is initialized from A.

Comment: Kamil Cuk. Please, don't answer to non-asked question.

Comment: @KamilCuk: You have asserted the compiler does not know the value assigned to an object originated with a macro. But the question does not ask this. First, it is asking anout gdb, not the compiler. Second, the compiler does have some information about this, at least briefly, and compilers may put a lot of information into the debugging data. Third, OP does not necessarily want a perfect implementation reporting where a value truly originated. The values are distinctive enough that a lookup table may suffice. So the question is largely whether that can be implemented with gdb features.

Comment: @KamilCuk: Fifth, macro substitution does not operate by plain text. It uses preprocessor tokens.

Answer (score 0):

You might get something useful by creating a convenience function in python.  I tested using this C program:

```
int var1 = 1234;
int var2 = 4567;

int
main ()
{
  return 0;
}
```

And using this python script:

```
class ExpandMacro (gdb.Function):
    """Expand a value to a string, replacing with
    macro name where possible."""

    def __init__ (self):
        super (ExpandMacro, self).__init__ ("expand")

    def invoke (self, value):
        if (value == 1234):
            return "MY_MACRO"
        else:
            return str (value)

ExpandMacro ()
```

Then my GDB session:

```
(gdb) start
# .... snip ....
7     return 0;
(gdb) source lookup.py 
(gdb) p $expand (var1)
$1 = "MY_MACRO"
(gdb) p $expand (var2)
$2 = "4567"
(gdb) printf "var1=%s\n", $expand (var1)
var1=MY_MACRO
(gdb) printf "var2=%s\n", $expand (var2)
var2=4567
```

In order to use the returned value with a `%s` format inside `printf`, I always return a string.